# split a big HTML page to pages on client side

Tags: javascript, html

I have a huge HTML page which is mainly a form which is mostly like this:

```
<FIELDSET id= '1'>
<TABLE>
  <TR> </TR>
</FIELDSET>
</TABLE>
   .
   .
   .
<FIELDSET id= 'n'>
<TABLE>
  <TR> </TR>
</TABLE>
```

The number of  fieldsets are generated by dynamically on the server.

Question: On the client side I want to do a pagination for this huge page, so that only say,3 fieldset appear per page on the client. 
I don't want to change the way page is loading or form is being submitted currently.

Comment: Is it generated with the `</fieldset>` closing tag before the `</table>` closing tag (despite the `<table>` looking like it should be inside the `<fieldset>`), or is that a typo in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Well just a little tips you may use

```
$('fieldset')
document.querySelectorAll('fieldset')
```

will return you fields

in order to get show only i .. i+3 fieldsets you can use

```
var i = 3

$('fieldset').hide().each(function ( index, el) {
   if (index >= i && index < i+3) $(el).show() 
})


var fieldsets = [].slice(document.querySelectorAll('fieldset'))


for (var index in fieldsets) {
    var display = index < i && index >= i+3 ? 'none' : ''
    fieldsets[index].style.display = display
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination won't really help you in any way other than visual if done on the client side (no speed increases, load reductions, etc), but if that's what you want you can do it with DOM manipulation.  Something like the following might work for you:

```
    var i=0,sets=document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset'),len=sets.length;
    for(;i<len;i+=3) {
        // wrap sets[i] through sets[i+2], as long as they exist, in a div
        // if i !== 0, hide or minimize the div
    }
    // add controls to unhide/unminimize each div
```